# Sharing link in twitter with a preview iOS?

Tags: ios, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I had an application in which i am sharing a link to twitter using Uiactivityviewcontroller.its just showing the text and link in twitter in my TL.i want it to be shown like as in Facebook with an image extracted from the link.I am doing like this

```
    NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@“http://dhdhdh”];
  NSString* someText = @“fdfdfd”;

  UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *printData = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                                 initWithText:@"http://dhdhdh"];

  NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText,shareUrl,printData];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.
  NSArray *appActivities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UrlActivity alloc] init], nil];
  UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                          applicationActivities:appActivities];
          activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes=@[UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
        // activityViewController.


        [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: have you check login with other account and check your twit that show same what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

go to Build settings in targer-> link Binary with Library - > add "Social" framework

Import `#import <Social/Social.h>`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Avatarjakeneytiri.jpg"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [controller setInitialText:@"myShare"];
    [controller addImage:img];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    //wont work in simulator
}
```

Comment: I am using UIactivityviewcontroller